# limit add row in function not work, please help

Tags: javascript, function, limit, addition

This is a simple javascript add row with functions, then I don't know how to limit the additional row e.g. for max. 5 rows, any idea and pointer or example(s) I would be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
var newRow = document.all("tblGrid").insertRow();
oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='t1'><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this);'/>"; 
//if(oCell>=5)return; 
}
</script>
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count rows before adding. Rows are just an array within the table element - you can get its length via `length`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
    if (document.all("tblGrid").rows.length == 5) {
        return; // already max 5 rows
    }
    var newRow = document.all("tblGrid").insertRow();
    oCell = newRow.insertCell();
    oCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='t1'><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='removeRow(this);'/>"; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: @user - you are welcome. Feel free to follow the usual stackoverflow custom and if the answer was helpful, accept it by clicking the check-mark next to it and upvote by clicking the up-arrow. Thanks!

Comment: I did, but when i clicking the up-arrow then the message appear "Vote Up requires 15 reputations", so i failed. I am sorry i am new on stackoverflow i don't know how to increase my reputation as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter =1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(yourDivName){
if (counter==5) {
     *the code you want to execute if the limit is reached* }
else {
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = "<span id=''>Serial Number " + (counter + 1) + " : <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/></span>";
     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
     counter++;
     }
}
```